# How can I centre multiple images that are floated across more than one line?

Tags: html, css, image, css-float, center

I am using bootstrap and have a div that is "col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" which is in the centre of the page. Using php I am loading images (film posters) from a database in a while loop until all images are loaded. I have floated them and given them all margins to space them out a little, and they load on multiple lines. Above them is a centred h2 (the genre). How do I horizontally centre the images for each line? At the moment they align to the left of the div. I have tried a combination of things to centre them but none will have any affect.

Here is the code.

```
<div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2" id="genrecontent">
    <?php
        //get the genre name
        $genres = $db->query('SELECT name FROM genre WHERE id = '.($_GET['id']));
        $genre = $genres->fetch_object('genre');
    ?>
    <h2><?=$genre->name?></h2>
    <br/>
    <?php
        // get the films from the genre we are dealing with
        // ensuring we escape the GET string
        $films = $db->query('SELECT * FROM film WHERE genre_id = '.$db->real_escape_string($_GET['id']));
        while($film = $films->fetch_object('film')):
    ?>
    <a href="films.php?id=<?=$film->id?>">
        <img src="http://comp2203.ecs.soton.ac.uk/coursework/1415/assets/posters/<?=$film->id?>_medium.jpg" alt="film poster"/>
    </a>
    <?php
        endwhile;
    ?>
</div>
```

and here is the CSS

```
#genrecontent h2{
    text-align: center;
}

#genrecontent a{
    float: left;
}

#genrecontent img{
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 15px;
}
```

I realise that usually I could set the width of the div and the widths of the images and their margins to make a perfect spacing out but the div changes size responsively corresponding to the browser size and so I need to work out a way to float and centre them.

Comment: You could try - remove the `float:left` and add `#genrecontent {text-align:center;}` please post your output html and create a simple demo if you can.

Comment: thanks, this worked. I don't know why I didn't think of this, it's so simple. I think I was too focused on needing the float.

Comment: Alright, I posted it as an answer, it can be closed up if you want to accept it, sorry for the drama for the negative comments of your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood your question the first time around. To align multiple images on a line you want to set the display of the images to inline-block and then set the parent to text-align: center.

I made a fiddle that should help but your css would look like this:

```
img {
    width: 100px;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bxurz66w/